# populate ckeditor form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, ckeditor, populate

i  am trying to populate form from mysql data with Json parse in Jquery, everything was ok except the "**CKEDITOR Field / textarea**" always **blank**, this is my code

```
function populateForm(form, dataJSON)
{
    var data = $.parseJSON(dataJSON);
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var $ctrl = $("#"+form).find('[id='+key+']');
        if ($ctrl.is('select')){
            $('option', $ctrl).each(function() {
                if (this.value == value)
                    this.selected = true;
            });
        }
        else if ($ctrl.is('textarea')) {
            $ctrl.val(value);
        }
        else {
            switch($ctrl.attr("type")) {
                case "email":
                case "text":
                case "hidden":
                    $ctrl.val(value);
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    if (value == 'on')
                        $ctrl.prop('checked', true);
                    else
                        $ctrl.prop('checked', false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The CKEditor creates a widget that shows the text, which is separate from the original textarea.  Rather than updating the textarea yourself, if the CKEditor has already been initialised, you need to add the text to the widget programmatically, like this...

```
CKEDITOR.instances.IDofEditor.insertText(value);
```